# Shared library and multiple levels of link with static libraries

Tags: c++, dll, linker

Imagine you have a static lib from a vendor : `libvendor.a`.

On top of this lib, we built a static library adding new features which uses some symbols of `libvendor.a`, let's call it `libteam.a`. So, `libteam.a` contains some symbols of `libvendor.a` as `libvendor.a` is a static library.

Now, we developed our 'components' as shared libraries, let's say `libcomponent1.dll`, `libcomponent2.dll`. These components use some features from `libteam.a` and from `libvendor.a`, so we linked to `libvendor.a` and `libteam.a`.

In the end, we have the executable `test.exe` using `libcomponent1.dll` and some features of `libvendor.a` so we link to both during link step. But, we get the following error multiple times during link  :

`multiple definition of symbol...`, symbols initially defined in `libvendor.a` but also available in `libteam.a` (due to link) so the error...

If I remove `libvendor.a` during link step of `libcomponent1.dll` library, I get `undefined reference to ...` error during build of `test.exe`, as symbols are not available in `libteam.a`... So I think it's right to link `libcomponent1.dll` to `libvendor.a` and `libteam.a`, fix me if I'm wrong.

I guess we're doing something wrong or maybe we can't do that... 
The idea is to have a `libcomponent1.dll` that we can easily distribute and link to applications. People will also surely need `libvendor.a`, but it's not an issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: I'm using MinGW so gcc.

Comment: I'd try playing with the link order, something like `test.exe libcomponent1.dll libteam.a libvendor.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two approaches:

1. Stop linking libraries to each other.  Instead, let your shared libraries have unresolved symbols which will be resolved when they are loaded by your executable which will link the static libraries.
2. Do "whole-archive" linking of your libraries.  Since you're using GCC, the options you need for this are something like:

   ```
   gcc -o libteam.a -Wl,--whole-archive -lvendor -Wl,--no-whole-archive ...
   ```

   This way you will link not just "some" symbols from `libvendor.a`, but all of them, so you never need to link `libvendor.a` into anything else that uses `libteam.a`.

Comment: Thank you, the first option works fine ! Is it a good practice to let unresolved symbols in shared libraries ?

Comment: @r2d2leboss: Yes, it's typical and a fine practice.

Comment: Ok perfect. I did the test on Linux first but I'm unable to build a shared lib on Windows using MinGW with the same command line without a lot of "undefined reference" (which is normally allowed in a shared lib ?). Does DLL allows to have undefined reference (compare to SO) ? Is there something specific on Windows ? Even adding "-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all", it does nothing.

Comment: On Windows, try the second approach in my answer, e.g. build a DLL which contains all symbols from `libvendor.a`.